# terminal - why am I getting this makefile error?

Tags: makefile, g++, macos-catalina

I am trying to run makefile but getting this error.

"make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop."

I have followed all the standards for makefile and referred many posts regarding this error but none of them helped me. anyone has a solution for this which isn't on the internet.

ouput as follows:

```
yuliam-MBP:~ yuliamosh$ cd /Users/yuliamosh/Documents/make1/
yuliam-MBP:make1 yuliamosh$ ls
Makefile.make   a.out       main.cpp    message.cpp message.h
yuliam-MBP:make1 yuliamosh$ g++ main.cpp message.cpp
yuliam-MBP:make1 yuliamosh$ ./a.out
Makefile Example!
yuliam-MBP:make1 yuliamosh$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
yuliam-MBP:make1 yuliamosh$
```

Answer (score 0):

gnu make assume you name the file just `Makefile`. So all you should need to do is rename `Makefile.make` to `Makefile`.

The hint in the error message is: `no makefile found`

Comment: See also the manual.  For example: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Arguments.html

Comment: I have named it as Makefile itself but in the terminal, it shows with .make extension I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

It was an editor problem. I used vim to edit my Makefile. Now it's working successfully.